# Does Android support JSR 82?

Tags: android

I want to connect Android phone to other devices using JSR 82.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `javax.bluetooth` is absent from the Android API, so the reply is probably "No".

You will have to implement it yourself, or use `android.bluetooth`.